# How to insert a new record with LinqToSql?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Googling shows there is to be an "Add" method for this, but there seems to be no Add or anything alike in my LinqToSQL table classes. I've tried "Attach", but with no effect :-(

I use VS2010, .Net 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

My tables have no surrogate ID but a natural composite primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourDatacontext.yourlinqClass.InsertOnSubmit(new yourlinqClass());

yourDatacontext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: The context doesn't actually have the `InsertOnSubmit` method.  It's the Table<T> property that has it.

Comment: bloddy hell. thanks again. didn't actually try it.. just went from memory :)

Answer (score 2):

It's `InsertOnSubmit()` for LinqToSQL:

```
ctx.MyClass.InsertOnSubmit(newinstance);
```